# How to send multiple images to server using retrofit 2.3.0 in android?

Tags: android, server, retrofit, send, android-image

I tried below code to send multiple images to server through retrofit 2.3.0
but its not worked to me :

```
 Map<String, RequestBody> multiPartMap = new HashMap<>();

    multiPartMap.put("originalImgBlob",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"),  mFiles.get(0)));
    multiPartMap.put("img430Blog",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png;base64"),  mFiles.get(1)));
    multiPartMap.put("img200Blog",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png;base64"),  mFiles.get(2)));
    multiPartMap.put("img100Blog",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png;base64"),  mFiles.get(3)));
    multiPartMap.put("blurResponseBlob",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png;base64"),  mFiles.get(4)));
```

and send this multipart data to server like this :

```
 Call<JsonObject> stringCall = mServerUtilities.getStringClassService(getApplicationContext(), "").postImage(Singleton.getInstance().getUserRegDetailsRespModel().getMId(), ACTION_TYPE_UPLOAD_NEW_PIC,multiPartMap);


        stringCall.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<JsonObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull retrofit2.Response<JsonObject> response) {

                Log.d("fb_regist_response", "--->" + "" + response);


            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                mUtilities.showAlert(t.getMessage(), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                Log.d("onFail_fb_regist_res", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

and this is the final retrofit interface:

```
    @Multipart
@POST("/api/mbrphotos/prfImgIU/{memberId}/{actionType}")
Call<JsonObject>  postImage(@Path("memberId") String memberId,
                            @Path("actionType") String actionType,
                            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> multipartTypedOutput);
```

I need to send multiple images to server  through retrofit 2.3.30 only ,can anyone suggest me to do that 
I got error: 204(no content )

Comment: 204 is not an error, 204 means "The server has **successfully** fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body". From https://httpstatuses.com/204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using @Part try @Field

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/api/mbrphotos/prfImgIU/{memberId}/{actionType}")
    Call<JsonObject> postImage(@Part("memberId") RequestBody memberId,
                               @Part("actionType") RequestBody actionType,
                               @Part MultipartBody.Part[] multipartTypedOutput);
```

and in your **`Activity`** use this method to send the post

```
public void sendPost(String memberId, String actionType) {
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();

MultipartBody.Part[] multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartBody.Part[imageModelArrayList.size()];

for (int index = 0; index < imageModelArrayList.size(); index++) {
    Log.d("Upload request", "requestUploadSurvey: survey image " + index + "  " + imageModelArrayList.get(index).path);
    File file2 = new File(imageModelArrayList.get(index).path);
    RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file2);
    multipartTypedOutput[index] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFiles[]", file2.getPath(), surveyBody);
}

RequestBody memberId1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), memberId);
RequestBody actionType1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), actionType);

apiService.postImage(memberId1, actionType1, multipartTypedOutput).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        Log.d("fb_regist_response", "--->" + "" + response);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("onFail_fb_regist_res", t.getMessage());
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

}
```

Comment: hi, thank u for ur response,  I obeyed  u , but I got 400 bad input error

Comment: where did u get  400 bad input error, i mean at which line.

Comment: sir have a look this  url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150288/bad-request-while-sending-multiple-images-through-retrofit-2-3-0-in-android

Comment: i got response 400 bad input